# How to add hashtags for Instagram photos using instabot in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm uploading images to Instagram successfully using **instabot** but how to add a **single hashtag** or a **list of hashtags** within this code.

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="swarna7725", password="***********")
bot.upload_photo("thanks.jpg", caption="Your Support Always Needed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work directly... But if is not working, what I did is, save all text from caption into a variable before instantiate your bot object, and then just assign caption to it.

```
from instabot import Bot

text_with_hashtag = "Add your caption text here and then your hashtags as follows #here #you #can #use #your #hashtags"

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="swarna7725", password="***********")
bot.upload_photo("thanks.jpg", caption=text_with_hashtag)

#note that captions = your variable with text and hashtags
```